# Hugo - how to make pages in other languages

Tags: internationalization, hugo

I have 3 languages for my project, en, es and ch.
When I add a contact page ( `site/content/contact.html` ) I'm able to access it from `/contact` but I'm expecting to also be able to get to `/es/contact` and just i18n to translate everything.

Instead `/es/contact` gives me the poop emoji.

Can someone tell me what I need to to to get that path to work?

Answer (score 1):

possibly some more information so we can help you out. Did you, as of yet, implement i18n, if so, how?
https://phrase.com/blog/posts/i18n-tutorial-how-to-go-multilingual-with-hugo/
is an excellent example of how to do this.
Are you waiting for a translation to be automatically done for you?
Please clarify and I'm sure we can assist, but the above will be of great assistance as a primer.
(The path for the translated content and how to set this up is covered in the above as well)

Comment: Thanks but I've since switched to gatsby / next. I was led to believe the hugo community was more active than it really is I think.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for answering. In the future, or if someone else sees this, I've found (I've never dealt with the Gatsby community) that the Hugo community is MUCH more active on: https://discourse.gohugo.io/ - for future reference - if it helps...